# How to count number of notification and display single icon in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have multiple Android notification, but when I send a message from my web server, the android device creates a new notification icon on status bar. I want to count the number of unread notification, display it on `statusbar` with single icon, and when a notification is read, the notification has to change the number of unread notification count. How can I do it? It's look like "3 Others" in this image: [Notification Icon](http://byebye.128pro.net/NotMagnify.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the answer here: [How to give counter if more than one Notifications are there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203541/how-to-give-counter-if-more-than-one-notifications-are-there)

You just have to set [`Notification.number`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#number):

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.direction, "Cool Notification",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        /********LIKE THIS*********/
        notification.number = notificationCount++;
        /********LIKE THIS*********/

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Cool Notification Title",
                "updated notificaiton message", null);


        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(R.id.my_motification, notification);
```

You have to send your notification through the `NotificationManager.notify` method, with the same id all the time. As the documentation says, the id is a unique identifier for that notification within your application. If you reuse the same id, it will just update the text and number for that notification.

To check when the user clicks on the notification, you need to provide a PendingIntent (see the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)). To check when the user clears the notifications, you need to use the [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) that is only available in the Api Level 11.

Comment: Update : Now you can use `NotificationCompat` class in Android support package. http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html

Comment: @BharathMg I cant't find number in NotificationxCompact!

Answer (score 3):

Well this codes work for me:

```
Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.yourownpicturehere, 
                                   getString(R.string.noticeMe), 

System.currentTimeMillis());    
PendingIntent i=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                           new Intent(this, NotifyActivity.class),0);

n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), 
                     getString(R.string.title),
                     getString(R.string.message), i);
n.number=++count;
n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
n.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
n.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
n.ledARGB = 0xff0000ff;
n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

// Now invoke the Notification Service
String notifService = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(notifService);
mgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, n);
```

Follow this [link](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/06/android-notification-tutorial-and-how.html) for complete tutorial.
I think the `n.number=++count;` is the one responsible for counting the notification

Answer (score -1):

You will need a different bitmap for each number, and set the icon to show the bitmap that corresponds to the number of notifications left.

To keep track of the notifications, you can simply set a counter in SharedPreferences, add to it with each new notification, and reduce by one when a notification is read (or to zero if you show all the notifications at once).

Comment: @ Aleadam: I already add counter in SharedPreferences, but i don't know how to determine notification is readed or unread and set the value of counter? How can i catch this events?

Comment: there is a native way to do that with Android without using your own bitmaps. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203541/how-to-give-counter-if-more-than-one-notifications-are-there