# How to show message count in notification

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I am using Google's Push notification and I want to show the number of notification in the notification icon, instead of showing the multiple notifications. Something like this -

[image]

Is there a method or something in the Notification Class for android?

Comment: This link might help you 

[Notification][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381157/how-to-count-number-of-notification-and-display-single-icon-in-android

Comment: Thanks RShetty01. It looks like it has the answer for me. I will try ths later today.

Answer (score 0):

the Notification class should be used for displaying notifications on the top bar (like the Gmail notifications). From what I understood, you can just use a normal TextView applying some styles to make it look nice and place it inside your screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the icon you will display when the notification is created.
With `.setsmallIcon()` I think.

I also encourage you to implement bigtextviews for JellyBean. NoficationCompat2 is a good library to manage this elegantly on different Android versions.